# agent sales report, sums all their sales and minimized display result by total sales

Tags: php, mysql

i have 3 table user, products and sales

```
user
UID | NAME
 1  | agent1
 2  | agent2
 3  | agent3
 4  | agent4
 5  | agent5

products
PID | PNAME
 1  |   P1
 2  |   P2
 3  |   P3

sales
SID | UID | PID | SALES_CREATED
 1  |  3  |  1  | 2013-07-13 01:15:04
 2  |  1  |  1  | 2013-07-13 01:25:34
 3  |  3  |  1  | 2013-07-13 02:01:34
 4  |  3  |  1  | 2013-07-13 02:45:34
 5  |  5  |  1  | 2013-07-13 02:56:34
 6  |  5  |  1  | 2013-07-13 03:21:34
 7  |  2  |  3  | 2013-07-13 03:38:34
 8  |  3  |  2  | 2013-07-13 03:51:34
 9  |  4  |  2  | 2013-07-13 04:25:34
 10 |  3  |  1  | 2013-07-13 04:45:04
 11 |  1  |  3  | 2013-07-13 04:55:34
 12 |  2  |  2  | 2013-07-13 05:01:34
 13 |  1  |  3  | 2013-07-13 05:15:34
 14 |  5  |  3  | 2013-07-13 05:36:34
 15 |  5  |  3  | 2013-07-13 06:21:34
```

where the results of sales per agent is: (sort by user UID)

```
  user   | P1 | P2 | P3 |
 agent1  | 1  | 0  | 2  |
 agent2  | 0  | 1  | 1  |
 agent3  | 4  | 1  | 0  |
 agent4  | 0  | 1  | 0  |
 agent5  | 2  | 0  | 2  |
```

now, i want a result to sort user that has a greatest sale by P1 and a minimum of 3 result only, and the result will be like this

```
  user   | P1 | P2 | P3 |
 agent3  | 4  | 1  | 0  |
 agent5  | 2  | 0  | 2  |
 agent1  | 1  | 0  | 2  |
```

can you guys give me a best mysql_query to show that result?

Comment: What happens if agent 3 sells 4 P1s and 10 P3s, does he end up at the bottom of the list? or the top?

Comment: all i want is the result of 3 topseller agents for P1, and display it from 1st topseller agent to 3rd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, something like this...

```
 SELECT uid
      , SUM(pid=1) p1
      , SUM(pid=2) p2
      , SUM(pid=3) p3 
   FROM sales 
  GROUP 
     BY uid 
  ORDER 
     BY p1 DESC
      , p2 DESC
      , p3 DESC;
 +-----+------+------+------+
 | uid | p1   | p2   | p3   |
 +-----+------+------+------+
 |   3 |    4 |    1 |    0 |
 |   5 |    2 |    0 |    2 |
 |   1 |    1 |    0 |    2 |
 |   2 |    0 |    1 |    1 |
 |   4 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
 +-----+------+------+------+
```

If handling the display logic at the application level, then your query can be simplified to something more scalable, like this...

```
 SELECT uid
      , pid
      , COUNT(*)
   FROM sales 
  GROUP 
     BY uid,pid;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer was very useful, can send me a link where i can study advance in mysql?

Comment: This is a basic `pivot table query`. Note that it's often better to return a simple ordered list, and handle the display logic at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

I am only answering because (1) I am bored, and (2) I wanted a brain teaser exercise. I typically do not like to answer when people post and run (don't respond to anyone's comments/posts), or provide what they have tried (no query).
 If you want better/more help on SO in the future, it would be beneficial to post the query that you have tried, and when using complex/diverse data like this to create a sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/

So with that caveat, here is how you can get your desired results

```
SELECT 
   user.NAME as user, 
   SUM(PID=1) as P1,
   SUM(PID=2) P2,
   SUM(PID=3) P3 
FROM
   sales
LEFT JOIN 
   user
ON 
   user.UID = sales.UID
GROUP BY 
   sales.UID
HAVING 
   P1+P2+P3 >= 3
ORDER BY 
   P1 DESC, P2 DESC, P3 DESC;
```

and here is the sqlfiddle example that shows it in action - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3405/8

Comment: Why the 'HAVING' part? I think the OP just wanted a LIMIT!?!